# how to edit a text file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file like this example:

```
>chr1:368597-368634
ATGATATAATAAGCCCTTCTCATTAAACATGATATGG
>chr1:879533-879955
GGTTGCCGGGGGTAGGGGTGGGGCCACACAAATCTCCAGGAGCCACCACTCAACACAATGGCCCTGCCTCCCACCGCTTTATTTCTTTCGGTTTCGGATGCAAA
ACAAAAAATTTTAAAAGAAAATGTGACTTCAAAGGAAAGGAACAAATTTTCAAAGACTTGGGGGAGTGAAGGCAGAGCCTGGTGCAGATGGACGAGGTCTGCAG
GCCTGT
>chr1:879533-879955
GGTTGCCGGGGGTAGGGGTGGGGCCACACAAATCTCCAGGAGCCACCACTCAACACAATGGCCCTGCCTCCCACCGCTTTATTTCTTTCGGTTTCGGATGCAAA
GCCTGT
>chr1:879533-879639
GGTTGCCGGGGGTAGGGGTGGGGCCACACAAATCTCCAGGAGCCACCACTCAACACAATGGCCCTGCCTCCCACCGCTTTATTTCTTTCGGTTTCGGATGCAAA
AC
```

the first line of each group which is `ID`, starts with `>` and the next line is a sequence of characters. in the second line I wan to keep the last 29 and remove the the rest. so the out put would look like this:

```
>chr1:368597-368634
ATAAGCCCTTCTCATTAAACATGATATGG
>chr1:879533-879955
GTGCAGATGGACGAGGTCTGCAGGCCTGT
>chr1:879533-879955
TTTCTTTCGGTTTCGGATGCAAAGCCTGT
>chr1:879533-879639
TTTATTTCTTTCGGTTTCGGATGCAAAAC
```

how can I do that using `awk` ?

Answer (score 1):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'r~/^>/{ print r ORS substr($0, length-28) }{ r=$0 }' a1
```

The output:

```
>chr1:368597-368634
ATAAGCCCTTCTCATTAAACATGATATGG
>chr1:879533-879955
GTGCAGATGGACGAGGTCTGCAGGCCTGT
>chr1:879533-879955
TTTCTTTCGGTTTCGGATGCAAAGCCTGT
>chr1:879533-879639
TTTATTTCTTTCGGTTTCGGATGCAAAAC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^>/||$0=substr($0, length($0)-28)' file
```

above awk one-liner should help you:

```
kent$  awk '/^>/||$0=substr($0, length($0)-28)' f
>chr1:368597-368634
ATAAGCCCTTCTCATTAAACATGATATGG
>chr1:879533-879955
GTGCAGATGGACGAGGTCTGCAGGCCTGT
>chr1:879533-879955
TTTCTTTCGGTTTCGGATGCAAAGCCTGT
>chr1:879533-879639   
TTTATTTCTTTCGGTTTCGGATGCAAAAC
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another awk using modulus to decide whether to print or process:

```
$ awk 'NR%2;!(NR%2){print substr($0,length()-28)}' file
>chr1:368597-368634
ATAAGCCCTTCTCATTAAACATGATATGG
>chr1:879533-879955
GTGCAGATGGACGAGGTCTGCAGGCCTGT
>chr1:879533-879955
TTTCTTTCGGTTTCGGATGCAAAGCCTGT
>chr1:879533-879639
TTTATTTCTTTCGGTTTCGGATGCAAAAC
```